# Display textarea value as list format in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-helper

Iam using aldeed:autoform along with materialize package have this textarea and i want to display the value in it as list format on every line break \n like.

```
<ul>
  <li>this is is one line break paragraph </li>
  <li>this is second line break paragraph </li>
</ul>
```

Please tell me how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The auto form will save it to the database, so on the view side where you are showing it, you can create a helper that will split the text area into separate lines, and then iterate through those in the template.

Here is a quick example.

Inside your helpers:

```
Template.templateName.helpers({
  lines: function() {
    return this.textAreaField.split("\n");
  }
};
```

Then inside your template:

```
<ul>
  {{#each lines}}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks alot man. it worked :) though there is little typo in your comment as each should end with {{/each}}. its just a little thing but if someone else stumbles upon this issue they shouldn't be confused. hope i didn't offend you. BTW thank you very much for that answer

Comment: can you please look through this question too http://stackoverflow.com/q/30676261/4320328 and help me with it @Rurri