# Populate the select field from collection and filter according to the selected value in meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-helper

I am a new guy in Meteor. I have select box which i want  to populate from the mongo collection itself.I tried doing this as below but doesn't work

```
<template name="clist">

<div class="input-field">
 <select>
   <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    {{#each company}}
      <option>{{ccategory}}</option>
    {{/each}}
 </select>
</div>

<ul class="collection" id="listings">
{{#each company}}
 <li>
  {{> employees}}
</li>
{{/each}}
```

```
</template>
```

And also i want to filter the data in mytemplate according to the value selected in the dropdownlist. Please help me iam stuck in this.

this is exactly what i have now but the problem is the dropdownlist is populating based on the results of all the listings not directly from the schema and is repetitive of all values. and i am using the same returning helper for both these values like return company.find(). Please help me

Answer (score 2):

Well in order to populate the select, you should change the {{#each}} down to the select, like this.

```
<select>
  <option disabled selected>Choose option</option>
{{#each company}}
  <option>{{category}}</option>
{{/each}}
</select>
```

Because if you put the `{{#each}}` at the top of the `<select>` tag meteor will create 1 select for each company.

And the company helper should be simple like a simple `return company.find();`

Now if you want to filter, there are many options to accomplish this, one could be this.

I like to use [ReactiveDict();](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict) , so i will use on this example.

Install it `meteor add reactive-dict`

```
Template.example.onCreated(function(){
 var self = this;

 self.example = new ReactiveDict();

self.example.setDefault( 'valueToFilter' , null);
});
```

Now on some event like `change`, do the following.

```
Template.example.events({
 'change select' : function( event, template ) {

   var instance = Template.instance();

   instance.example.set( 'valueToFilter' event.target.value ); //or use $('select').val()  whatever you like to take the value;
  }
})
```

Now show the results.

```
Template.example.helpers({

 showSelectedValues : function(){

  var instance = Template.instance();

  return Companies.find( { name : instance.example.get( 'valueToFilter' )} );
 }
})
```

This should give you a big picture, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have done what you asked to poppulate the dropdownlist. i updated my question with the exact code iam using and further elaborated the problem i am facing. please have a look and help me