# Filter collection based on select dropdown box in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

I am trying to filter my collection based on the selection of value from select dropdown list. I have tried with the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693084/loading-fields-from-collection-into-select-field-and-filtering-it-based-on-selec) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676261/populate-the-select-field-from-collection-and-filter-according-to-the-selected-v) and its not working enough for me. Below is the template where i want to filter.the select dropdown is in another template `categoryFilter`  which iam calling here using `{{> categoryFilter}}` to filter the list of collections under `{{#each car}}` block. The field i am using in schema is `ccategory` which i want to filter

```
<template name="carsList">
  <div class="col s12 filter-holder">
        <div class="col m4 s4 filter-box">
          {{> categoryFilter}}
        </div>
 </div>

<div class="col s12">
 <ul class="collection" id="listings">
{{#each cars}}
<li>
  {{> carItem}}
</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
</div>
</template>
```

this is my existing helper for calling all cars

```
Template.carsList.helpers ({
'allCars': function() {
  return Cars.find();
},
});
```

this is how my event look like for this. `var pageSession=ReactiveDict();`

```
 Template.carsList.events({
  "click .categoryselection": function(e, t){
 var text = $(e.target).text();
  pageSession.set("selectedCategory",text);
 }
 });
```

I am using `ReactiveDict()` package for this filtering.Am i doing it right till now? How can i filter the values and call them on the `<ul>` list and filter `<li>` values.Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are only storing one value at a time (the selected category), there is no real need to use a `ReactiveDict` for this case, is there? If so, you could do it with a [ReactiveVar](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg) instead:

```
 Template.carsList.onCreated(function () {
   this.selectedCategory = new ReactiveVar();
 });

Template.carsList.helpers ({
'allJobs': function() {
  var category = Template.instance().selectedCategory.get();
  return Cars.find(category ? {ccategory: category} : {});
},
});

 Template.carsList.events({
  "click .categoryselection": function(e, t){
 var text = $(e.target).text();
  t.selectedCategory.set(text);
 }
 });
```

If you still want to use a `ReactiveDict` for multiple filter values such as `ccategory` and `city`, you could go with:

```
Template.carsList.helpers ({
'allJobs': function() {
  var filter = {};
  var category = pageSession.get("selectedCategory");
  var city = pageSession.get("selectedCity");
  if (city)
    filter.city = city;
  if (category)
    filter.ccategory = category;
  return Cars.find(filter);
},
});

 Template.carsList.events({
  "click .categoryselection": function(e, t){
 var text = $(e.target).text();
  pageSession.set("selectedCategory",text);
 },
  "click .cityselection": function(e, t){
 var text = $(e.target).text();
  pageSession.set("selectedCity",text);
 }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. But i have one more selectdropdown filter on the same template that i want to use. how should i go about the helper for that and how should i call it from template? template is same `carsList`. on this same listing `<ul class="collection" id="listings">
{{#each cars}}
<li>
  {{> carItem}}
</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>` how can i filter according to the second filter?

Comment: The second filter is on a different field than `ccategory`? If so, just add one new key to your `ReactiveDict` and update it according to the select event. Then, get it in the same helper as selectedCategory and check if it exists. If it does, add the filter to the `Cars.find` call

Comment: I am using now `ReactiveVar`. Yes the filter is not on category. Say that the other filter is about `city`. how can i call it from template?

Comment: Updated my answer. Using ReactiveDict. But you can use ReactiveVar as well!

Comment: Can you please look into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829105/dopdownlist-is-being-populated-with-limited-values-instead-of-values-from-total) of mine. i am stuck in this one very badly. @BraveKenny